# jQuery toggle not working after addClass is called

Tags: jquery

So I have a click function that toggles a button on my page. I also have another function that adds a class to the button if a checkbox is checked. My problem is if the class is added to the button then the click function is hit the toggle does not change the inline style.

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
    $(".anotherBtn").toggle();
}


function getsCalledWhenCheckBoxIsChecked() {
    $(".anotherBtn").addClass("hideBtn");
}

<style>
.hideBtn {
    display: none !important;
}
</style>
```

This is part of a much larger system and I have greatly over simplified the code simply to display what is generally happening. When viewing the page in chrome with developer tools I can see that when the "hideBtn" class is added the inline style does not change when toggle is hit yet it does on other elements. When the class is removed it works again.

Toggle works

```
<button class="anotherButton" style="display: inline-block;"></button> 
<button class="anotherButton" style="display: none;"></button>
```

Toggle does not change to display: none

```
<button class="anotherButton hideBtn" style="display: inline-block;"></button>
<button class="anotherButton hideBtn" style="display: inline-block;"></button>
```

Any thoughts or help is appreciated.

Comment: you don't have an element with the id `anotherBtn` so `$("#anotherBtn")` must be `$(".anotherBtn")`,  also I think the problem occurs because `.hideBtn`'s `display:none;` is flagged as `!important`

Comment: Sorry the "#anotherBtn" was a typo of me writing this question not reflected in the actual code.

$("btn") is just another button on the page that triggers the click function. 

Unfortunately I can not share the production code for the problem but I will work on a fiddle to display this error.

Comment: I thought about the display:none !important but I removed it and it still does not change the inline style when the new class is there.

Comment: Just created a jsfiddle and it works fine, so there must be something else in the code changing it back I am investigating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that when you use `display: none !important;` it will override the inline style `style="display: inline-block;"` that `toggle()` will generate.

The specific issue is using `!important`

You can confirm this in a browser console by inspecting the CSS rules applicable to the element.

There are a number of workarounds but the first one would be to see if you really need `!important` at all

Comment: Okay this is the case, unfortunately I do need the important but your right the toggle thinks that the property is display: none and hence is going to display:inline-block even tho the inline style says display:inline-block.

Can you give me an example of another workaround were I can force the inline style to change?

Comment: can look into using `cssText` property, or use jQuery `attr('style', 'display: inline-block !important')`

Comment: personally my  bet is you could easily make your css rule have a more specific selector so you wouldn't need `important` at all